# Javascript random text generate randomly

Tags: javascript, random, range

I want create javascript random script which makes random text which every text has assigned random integer to it. and everything will be separated by , i.e
es45d4dw 2, hrt54345 5, etc.
Every item should be generated at random different time from range. How can i do that?

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myFunction, getRndInteger(1000, 10000));

function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function myFunction() {
  var para = document.createElement("t");
  var t = document.createTextNode(makeid());
  para.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(para);
}

function makeid() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}
```

Comment: and what is your problem? what is not working?

Comment: This code just generates text at state one interval.

Comment: A bettet option is to just use a recursive `setTimeout`

Comment: I think there is too much content now. I should just paste full code and simple question What I want as result (trying to do)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is use setTimeout and recursion

```
var myVar = setTimeout(myFunction, getRndInteger(1000,10000));

function myFunction() {
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  var t = document.createTextNode(makeid());
  para.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(para);
  myVar = setTimeout(myFunction, getRndInteger(1000, 10000));
}
```

This way getRndInteger is reset with each calling.